# Проверка на авторизацию Yii

Tags: php, yii

Добрый день!
Ситуация следующая: в проекте на yii сделана авторизация пользователей, но вот как сделать, так чтобы не приходилось в каждом из модулей в actionIndex() делать проверку примерно следующего содержания:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        $this->actionLogin();
    else
        $this->redirect('/projects');
}
```

То есть из любой точки приложения, неавторизированного юзера должно редиректить на страницу авторизации.

Comment: а в йии есть понятие "файрволл"? т.е. по маске маршрута требовать причастность юзера к какой-то группе.

Comment: @digi Почти - по конкретному действию, называется это фильтром accessControl. Почему в ответах все призывают городить такие конструкции в контроллере (и уж тем более не в beforeAction) - я не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать наследника CController и в нем в init сделать такую проверку.
Все ваши контроллеры при этом наследовать от него.

Answer (score 4):

Нет, я все-таки не вытерплю

```
SuperController extends CController {
    public function actionSupremum() {}
    public function actionExtremum() {}
    public function actionConundrum() {}
    public function filters() {
        return array('accessControl'); // включаем функционал контроля доступа
    }
    public function actionRules() {
        return array(
            // закрываем отдельный экшен от всех, кроме группы админы
            array('allow', 'actions' => array('supremum'), 'users' => array('admin')),
            array('deny', 'actions' => array('supremum'), 'users' => array('*')),
            // оставляем открытым для всех один экшен
            array('allow', 'actions' => array('extremum'), 'users' => array('*')),
            array('deny', 'users' => array('?')), // закрываем все оставшиеся экшены  от неавторизованных пользователей
        );
    }
}
```

Не нужно копаться в конструкторах и beforeAction, в Yii все давно уже [написано](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/topics.auth#sec-5). Все равно настанет момент, когда одно действие надо приоткрыть, другое банить в ночное время суток, третье блокировать по групповому принципу.

Comment: так вы правильно делаете, что не терпите. Я к примеру с вашего поста понял как в YII acl организовывать. Хотя Yii в глаза на видел.

Comment: Это все хорошо. Но как с помощью рулзов организовать редирект?

Comment: И снова доки:
> При неудачной авторизации, т.е. когда пользователю запрещено выполнять указанное действие, происходит следующее:

> Если пользователь не аутентифицирован и в свойстве loginUrl компонента user задан URL страницы входа, браузер будет перенаправлен на эту страницу. Заметим, что по умолчанию loginUrl перенаправляет к странице site/login;
> Иначе будет отображена ошибка HTTP с кодом 403.

Comment: тогда уж не users а roles

Comment: @des1roer http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter - // optional, list of usernames (case insensitive) that this rule applies to. Use * to represent all users, ? guest users, and @ authenticated users. 
`'users'=>array('thomas', 'kevin'),`

Answer (score 1):

Можно как и описано выше сделать контроллер и от него наследоваться а в него записать примерно следующее.

```
protected function beforeAction($action) {

        if (Yii::app()->controller->action->id!=='login')
        if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) 
           $this->redirect('/login');

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

ну и он будет правда постоянно при каждом экшене проверять это. с одной стороны часто,да, но с другой никто неавторизованный не посмотрит ни один экшен.

Answer (score 0):

Я то конечно не по Yii но скажем в Zend есть PreDispach а у вас я нагуглил beforeAction
вот в нем и напишите ваши проверки и редиректы.